# Kafka ssl.keystore.password field does not accept value as char array

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a kafka client written in Java.How its done:

```
Properties props;
char[] keystorepwd = {t,e,s,t};
props.put("ssl.keystore.password",keystorepwd);

KafkaProducer<String,Object> = new KafkaProducer<String,Object>(props);
```

I checked the KafkaProducer doc and it says we can pass an Object in Properties instead of String. However, when I actually run it, I get the following error:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value [C@45bc4219 for configuration ssl.keystore.password: Expected value to be a string, but it was a [C
```

I see a similar error for AdminClient too:

```
Map<String,Object> adminClientProps = new HashMap<String,Object>();
adminClientProps.put("ssl.keystore.password",keystorepwd);
AdminClient admin = AdminClient.create(adminClientProps);
```

Same error for this as well.

I neither get a compilation error and in fact I verified that the code above is in sync with what is there in the Kafka documentation.

Please let me know if we can even pass a char array as value in the properties for kafka client or do we have to convert it to String?

Note: I know that we can pass the char array as a String instead by doing:

```
adminClientProps.put("ssl.keystore.password",new String(keystorepwd));
```

But we want the char array to be used as it is while creating the Kafka client instance instead of converting to String.

Thanks,
Om

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, although they may not think so. Any password should be supplyable as a `char[]`.

Comment: @user207421: That's what I suspect too. The KafkaProducer and AdminClient constructor itself allows you to pass any Object (which I guess includes char array too). But when you actually run, this fails.